# Pass JSON object to WebApi

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to post data from my web page to my RegistrationController Api. I see it when I submit the form, but when I hit my breakpoint on the WebApi, the parameter 'pilot' is null. Can someone tell me what I need to do to get the data to pass from the web page over to the Registration ApiController?

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869763/how-to-post-an-object-to-webapi), but it did not seem to work for me. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33895572/how-to-read-json-object-to-webapi), which was close to my question, mentioned that the model needed to annotated, but still did not work for me.

Button on cshtml page:

```
<button id="submitRegistration" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"  
    type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Angular RegistrationController:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
'use strict';

var sampleApp = angular.module('RegistrationApp', []);

sampleApp.controller('RegistrationController', function ($scope, $http) {
    var registrationData = {
        "firstname": $scope.firstname,
        "lastname": $scope.lastname,
        "faaNumber": $scope.faaNumber
    };

    $('#submitRegistration').click(function () {

        registrationData = {
            FirstName: $scope.firstname,
            LastName: $scope.lastname,
            FAANumber: $scope.faaNumber
        };

       // When I hit this debugger, the data is good.
       debugger;
        $.post("api/registration",
                JSON.stringify(registrationData),
                function (value) {
                $('#registrationMessage').append(value);
                },
                "json"
        );
    });
});
</script>
```

WebApi RegistrationController Class:

```
public class RegistrationController : ApiController
{
// *********** Pilot is null when the breakpoint hits here ************
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]PilotModel pilot)     
{
    this.RegisterPilot(pilot);

    var response = Request.CreateResponse<PilotModel>(HttpStatusCode.Created, pilot);

    return response;
}

private string RegisterPilot(PilotModel pilot)
{
    var result = string.Empty;

    ...

    return result;
}
}
```

Pilot Model:

```
[DataContract]
public class PilotModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FAANumber { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will take only one minute, give this a try:

```
$.post("api/registration",
                registrationData,
                function (value) {
                $('#registrationMessage').append(value);
                },
                "json"
        );
```

Comment: Removing the JSON.stringify() did it. I thought I needed that. I also saw that I did not the DataContract or DataMember attributes either. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to post the data from your angular code, you should be using `$http` service, which will take care of setting the proper content type as needed. Looks like you are already injecting the $http service to your controller.

```
var model = { FirstName: "Shyju",
              LastName: "Happy"
              FAANumber: "3454353"  };

$.http("api/registration",model)
  .then(function(response) {
      var result=response.data;
      console.log(result);
  }, function(response) {
      //error happened. Inform the user
  });
```

Ideally, you should move http calls to a data service and inject that data service to your angular controller.

If you still want to use jQuery ajax (which i would not recommend) ,you can convert your object to a json string and specify the `contentType` property to `"application/json"`. This approach will work even if your model has complex navigational properties.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data :JSON.stringify(model),
        url: "api/registration",
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
```

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226169/how-to-pass-json-post-data-to-web-api-method-as-object/20226220#20226220) which covers almost all the use cases of sending data to web api using ajax.

Comment: Yes, Angular already makes API calls easy. No need to go through jQuery to do it.

Comment: Be aware that not ALL headers you might think are actually set by $http are in fact set. Best to look at the default headers in chrome tools or whatever. There's a couple of gotchas in the new Asp.Net 5 framework in handling AJAX and redirects.

Comment: @shyju, thank you for the response. I have made changes per your recommendation, which works great. I will also look into moving the http calls into a data service. Just working through a little bit at a time as I try to   learn this.